# PHP MySQL DATEDIFF inside the SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $Query = 'SELECT agentname,agentid 
              FROM allagents 
              WHERE monthlysalary ' . $_POST["salaryoperator"] . ' ? 
                AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),hiredate) ' . $_POST["dayshiredoperator"] . ' ?';

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $Query))
    {
            $Bind_sal = 0;
            $Bind_days = 0;

            if ($_POST["msalarytolook"] != "") {$Bind_sal = $_POST["msalarytolook"];}
            if ($_POST["hireagetolook"] != "") {$Bind_days = $_POST["hireagetolook"];}

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"di",$Bind_sal,$Bind_days);  
        }
```

So I have the code above. Whenever I execute it, it does not return any result. The website has a search box where the user can choose to display the list of agents based on monthly salary and days since hired (weather greater than or less than).

I couldn't figure out what it isn't working, I get no result. `hiredate` is a date type column in MySQL database. `$_POST["salaryoperator"]` and `$_POST["dayshiredoperator"]` are either "=" or ">" or "<". I think the problem is at `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),hiredate)` which I thought would return the number of days since the agent was hired. Can someone help me see the problem? I had to use DATEDIFF since the goal is to have the query select only those agents with specified number of days in service. There's no column in the database for "days in service", I can only use DATEDIFF inside a query, it is not working.

**EDIT:**

I found a fix.

`'SELECT agentname,agentid FROM allagents WHERE monthlysalary ' . $SalaryOperator . ' ? AND hiredate ' . $HireDateOperator . ' (CURDATE() - INTERVAL ? DAY)'`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. May I ask how you would insert this operator in a query though? I don't think I can make it work with `Select WHERE monthlysalary ? ?` as my operator is also something that the user passes

Comment: @tadman He is using parameterised queries if you look closely. The variable substitution is for the `=` or `!=` parts of the query. Its a wierd idea I will give you that

Comment: Once you have prepared a query **you have to execute it !!!!!**

Comment: @RiggsFolly Prepared statements need placeholder values to be safe, and this one is preparing with `$_POST` data jammed right in there. Your observation that it isn't executed is the real problem here, you might want to add that as an answer.

Comment: Presumably there's only a fixed number of possible operators, so you can make it safe by doing something similar to `$salary_operator = in_array($_POST["salary_operator"], ["=", "<", ">"]) ? $_POST["salary_operator"] : "=";`

Comment: This is indeed Prepared Statement PDO, I only pasted this part of the query but yes there is an execute. This is built this way because the user will be selecting the operator like `equal to` or `greater than` then he specifies the number like `5` so like if he wants to display only those agent information who's been working for less greater than 5 days. He selects the dropdown button and choose if greater than or less than or equal to then he types the number.

Comment: @tadman Actually read the query now I have reformatted it so it is readable ... Note the use of `?`

Comment: Is the `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),hiredate)` correctly placed in there though? The problem is event if the hiredate is equal to 2016-6-20 and I try searching for Less than 20 it doesn't work. How do you test DATEDIFF result? I mean this seem to be a function that is being used inside the query so I can try to echo out the result

Comment: @RiggsFolly Although the values are escaped, it's completely reckless to put unescaped `$_POST` values in there no matter the reason. I haven't seen anyone use them for operators before, so this is a first, but not a prize you want to win.

Comment: @JinPards You absolutely **must** white-list which operators are valid and only insert known-good values in those places. You can't just arbitrarily inject raw `$_POST` data. If you've cleaned it up, you should use a different variable to indicate this. Everything received via `$_GET`, `$_POST` and so on should be considered hostile until proven otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @tadman, I thought at first since $Query will still pass through the Prepared Statement steps below then the process would clean it of any danger anyway, I mean I thought that was why that prepared statement section is there in the first place, but to be safe I followed your tip and passed the values to a variable first

Comment: Be extra careful not to include arbitrary `$_POST` data in there like you do in the question as it stands. Just because you think you're using them only for operators and even though you've prepared the values, it's still a textbook case of SQL injection.